# Do we need to use cookie for SAML2 login?

Tags: java, cookies, saml-2.0

I'm brand new to the world of SAML-2.
I've to implement SAML-2 for our web-based product using java.
My colleague has suggested following solution to implement SAML-2.

I just wanted to discuss whether it make sense...

Scenario A: John logs in for the first time since SSO has been implemented at his company

1. John points his browser at TMS
2. TMS does not find a SAML token stored as a cookie in the request header from John’s browser
3. John’s browser is redirected to the standard TMS login page
4. John enters his normal windows login credentials and hits ENTER
5. TMS successfully authenticates his credentials against his company’s IdP server, which in this case is ADFS using SAML
6. The SAML token is returned to TMS and saved in John’s browser as a cookie
7. John is now able to use TMS

Scenario B: John wants to use TMS again but has closed his browser

1. John opens a new instance and points it to TMS
2. TMS finds a SAML token stored as a cookie in the request header from John’s browser
3. TMS verifies that this token is valid and so John goes straight into TMS bypassing the login page

My question- is this a standard or correct approach? 
If we use cookie for remembering the SAML token, what if the user clears the cookie or doesn't want to keep cookie? In that case user will be directed to the login page every time...

Is there any resource (ie. book or online tutorial) that I can look into for this specific purpose?

Please let me know your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is rather close to how federated login works on the .NET platform. The SAML2 ticket is read when first received from the Idp, but on subsequent requests the Idp is not involved but rather a cookie.

However, on .NET the SAML2 token is not stored in the cookie, instead the cookie contains the identity information in a form that's suitable for .NET applications to avoid having to re-parse and re-validate the SAML2 token each time. The entire cookie is encrypted with a key that only the server knows, so there is no way for the user to tamper with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario B - user would be typically redirected to IDP (and automatically signed in without any user interaction in case session at IDP is still active) instead of re-using the cookie. After response from AFDS (step 6) applications typically store information about the authenticated user in HTTP Session and clear everything once user logs out or closes the browser.

But your approach can definitely work. In case user clears the cookie you simply initialize a new SAML authentication request with your ADFS. The key thing here is that ADFS shouldn't require user to authentication on every request, but as long as the ADFS session remains valid it should immediately return back to TMS with the SAML token, so user will typically need to authenticate only once in a while.